# Create mobile application with turn by turn navigation using google map APIs

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

We have one requirement in which we have to create iOS and Android mobile applications. Application has core features to show pins of different locations and show path + turn by turn navigation steps to particular pin.

Can I use https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/ to create such experience within my application using google map? I know it will charge as per usage limit post 2500 requests.

But will there be any rejection issue from google if we create such application?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use), not coding

Answer (score 2):

Sadly it is against Googles Maps Terms of use to create turn by turn navigation using their service. But as far as I know drawing path is fine and should not cause any problems.

> (c) No Re-Creating Google Products or Features. Customer will not use
>   the Services to create a product or service with features that are
>   substantially similar to or that re-create the features of another
>   Google product or service. Customer’s product or service must contain
>   substantial, independent value and features beyond the Google products
>   or services.  For example, Customer will not: (i) re-distribute the
>   Google Maps Core Services or pass them off as if they were Customer’s
>   services; (ii) create a substitute of the Google Maps Core Services,
>   Google Maps, or Google Maps mobile apps, or their features; (iii) use
>   the Google Maps Core Services in a listings or directory service or to
>   create or augment an advertising product; (iv) **combine data from the
>   Directions API, Geolocation API, and Maps SDK for Android to create
>   real-time navigation functionality substantially similar to the
>   functionality provided by the Google Maps for Android mobile app.**

Refer to 3.2.4c of their [license](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/?_ga=2.239835331.1937845890.1526384342-1921711428.1526384342)